# Webservice of xamarin forms doesn't open the new browser

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, webservice-client

With the string writing in the Entry on XAML, I'd like to modify the webpage and open it in a browser, but it's not working. Here is my MainPage.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace AntiFakeNews
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public string website;
        async void btnBuscar_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            string pesquisa = txtPesquisa.Text;
            var website = await client.GetStringAsync($"https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=pt-BR&as_sdt=0%2C5&q={pesquisa}&btnG=&lr=lang_pt");
            try
            {
                await Browser.OpenAsync(website, BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // An unexpected error occured. No browser may be installed on the device.
            }
        }

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get results of you manual put the URL into a browser on machine?  the website is secure (HTTPS) and I need to find out if your machine is setup properly to get a HTTPS response.

Comment: what does "not working" mean?  Are you getting an error or exception?  What specifically is happening, or not happening?  What is the value of `website` that you are retrieving from google?

Comment: @Jason the problem is that, when I hit the button, nothing happens and it should lead to the scholar google website with the results of the search

Comment: @jdweng how do I find out if it's properly to get a https response?

Comment: Use the debugger to step through the code

Comment: try using `Device.OpenUri(new System.Uri(website));` instead of `Browser.OpenAsync`